# Exploding txt file PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am having a problem exploding a txt file in PHP. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
Product N°3456788765
price: 0.09
name: carambar


Product N°3456789
price: 9
name: bread
```

So basically, I would like to have an array like:

```
array
    [0] => 
           [0] => Product N°3456788765
           [1] => price: 0.09
           [2] => name: carambar
    [] => 
           [0] => Product N°3456789
           [1] => price: 9
           [2] => name: bread
```

In the others questions, they used the explode function. Unfortunately, I don't know what to say to the function because delimiters are blank lines here...

I tried to make some research because when I go with a `strlen()` on a blank line, it shows 2 caracters. So after using `ord()` function, I saw that these two caracters were 13 and 10 in Ascii mode, but if I try a

```
$string = chr(13) . chr(10);
strcmp($string,$blankline);
```

It just doesn't work. I would have loved to use this `$string` in my explode delimiter...

Thank you all for you advices, first post here after many years finding answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is here:

```
    $text = file_get_contents('file.txt');
    $temp = explode(chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10),$text);
    $hands = array();
    foreach($temp as $hand){
        $hand = explode(chr(13) . chr(10),$hand);
        $hand = array_filter($hand);
        array_push($hands,$hand);
        $hand = array_filter($hand);
    }
    dd($hands);
```

I have two chr(13) . chr(10) when the product changes and one when it just changes the line. So it's working now!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
$file   =   file_get_contents("text.txt");
// This explodes on new line
// As suggested by @Dagon, use of the constant PHP_EOL
// is a better option than \n for it's universality
$value  =   explode(PHP_EOL,$file);
// filter empty values
$array  =   array_filter($value);
// This splits the array into chunks of 3 key/value pairs
$array  =   array_chunk($array,3);
```

**Gives you:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product N°3456788765
            [1] => price: 0.09
            [2] => name: carambar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product N°3456789
            [1] => price: 9
            [2] => name: bread
        )

)
```

Comment: its not always "\n" may want to provide a way to cover all options (`PHP_EOL`)

Comment: The first solution doesn't work, the explode() function expects to receive one string parameter and a second. `$file` is an array of strings. Each line is a line of the array...

The second solution can't work because I don't always have the same number of lines...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, depends on PHP version. I don't get that error on my version. You have to explode separately first to not get that error.

Comment: So you don't always have sets of three then is what your saying?

Comment: I get exactly the same error: `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given` on line `$value  =   explode("\n",$file);`. I don't see why put it out the function parameter would change something?

Comment: What is `$file` I assumed it was the contents of a file, not an array?

Comment: `$file = file('text.txt');` is an array, first line is $file[0], next line is $file[1], etc..

Comment: Oohh, I was assuming you were using something like `$file = file_get_contents("text.txt");`

Comment: If you are using `file()`, just skip explode, you've already exploded it. Feed the  `$file` into the `array_filter()`. If you want I can edit based on what you are doing with `file()`

Comment: Also, another option is using a line-by-line read of the file using `fopen()`, `feof()` and `fgets()` and as @Dagon suggests, using the constant `PHP_EOL` (End Of Line) instead of new line characters such as `\n`. This constant is *The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform* as noted in the PHP manual. That being said, using `file()` already places each line in an array so you can pretty much skip that part of the process...

Comment: I succeeded with the functions you gave me, I post the solution, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ok great! I guess my extra tid-bit was unnecessary. Cheers, glad it works!

Answer (score 2):

Don't make it complicated, just use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) combined with [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
<?php

    $lines = file("yourTextFile.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $chunked = array_chunk($lines, 3);
    print_r($chunked);

?>
```

Comment: I don't often need the ability to read line by line from a file, but I didn't know that the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` was an option in that function...good to know.

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, there is also anther flag, if you want to ignore the new line characters at the end of each line. (I personally use `file()` quite often)

Comment: Well, you have the best answer out of the three at any rate! Cheers.

Comment: The problem with your solution I think is because the number of lines can varie in function of the product..

Comment: @El_Matella If this is the case, you could just remove the filter, then check when the first empty line is, chunk the array then and remove the empty lines then